# Increment and decrement a number with Bootstrap design

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design

I am trying to get the UI shown below and need a border under the number exactly as in the image:

[image]

But I'm getting a different result with the code shown below. Can someone help me to design this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .input-number{
  margin: 0 15px;
width: 50px !important;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:150px;padding:50px;">
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number" disabled="disabled" data-type="minus" data-field="quant[1]">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
    </button>
  </span>
  <input type="text" name="quant[1]" class="form-control input-number" value="1" min="1" max="10">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="quant[1]">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
    </button>
  </span>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I remember working on a similar design of number input control flow, however, I am unable to access my work for this anymore. I wonder why HTML still does not provide a simple solution for this. The only thing I could come up with is the `<input type="number">` element, however, this does provide you with horizontal display of decrement & increment buttons, which obviously is not an uncommon shape of implementation nowadays.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply make the input field type as "number", which will automatically add increment and decrements button for you.. 
Here is a sample of code:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="enter amount">
```

Comment: Not in Chrome, in Firefox only.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```css
.input-number{
  
    width: 50px !important;
    text-align: center!important;
    font-weight: bold!important;
    font-size: 25px!important;
    height: 40px!important;
    border:none!important;
    border-bottom: solid 2px #ccc!important;
    box-shadow: none!important;
    position:relative;
}
.input-container{
    position: relative;
    height: 40px;
    display: block; 
    margin: 0 15px;
}
.input-container:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 2px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #ccc!important;
    z-index:10;
}
.input-container:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 2px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #ccc!important;
    z-index:10;
}
.btn-number{
    border-radius: 50%!important;
    background-color: #ccc!important;
    color: #fff!important;
    outline: none!important;
    font-size: 25px!important;
    padding: 3px!important;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div style="width:150px;padding:50px;">
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number" disabled="disabled" data-type="minus" data-field="quant[1]">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
    </button>
  </span>
  <span class="input-container">
  <input type="text" name="quant[1]" class="form-control input-number" value="1" min="1" max="10">
  </span>
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="quant[1]">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
    </button>
  </span>
  </div>
```

Comment: i got this design too, but failed to get border for input number, need border exactly as in image

Comment: Did you see this answer?

Answer (score 0):

you have to give styles to your `btn` and `input-number`classes like this:

```
.btn{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%,
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.btn .glyphicon {
  color: #fff;
}

.input-number {
  margin: 0 15px;
  width: 50px !important;
  border: none;
}
.input-number: after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  left: 50% - 50px;
}
```

Comment: what about border below to the number?

Comment: for that i gave style `.input-number:after` which design `5px height` border for your number at bottom.

Comment: no it dint work, can u update a new fiddle for your answer

Comment: sorry i cant due to lack of time if you'll please provide than i'll surely make change in that.

Answer (score 0):

```css
input.btneg {
  border-radius: 5cm;
  width: 40px;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: -30px;
  height: 0.8cm;
}

input.btpos {
  border-radius: 5cm;
  width: 40px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -30px;
  height: 0.8cm;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="btneg " value="-">
<input type="text" name="noq1" id="noq1" min="1" max="15" value="12">
<input type="button" class="btpos " value="+">
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, if possible you should [edit] your answer to include a short explanation of *how* this snippet answers the question. This helps to provide context and makes your answer much more useful for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h2>Simple Quantity increment buttons with Javascript </h2>
        
        
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button type="button" class="quantity-left-minus btn btn-danger btn-number"  data-type="minus" data-field="">
                                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
                                        </button>
                                    </span>
                                    <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" class="form-control input-number" value="10" min="1" max="100">
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button type="button" class="quantity-right-plus btn btn-success btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                                        </button>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var quantitiy=0;
   $('.quantity-right-plus').click(function(e){
        
        // Stop acting like a button
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get the field name
        var quantity = parseInt($('#quantity').val());
        
        // If is not undefined
            
            $('#quantity').val(quantity + 1);

          
            // Increment
        
    });

     $('.quantity-left-minus').click(function(e){
        // Stop acting like a button
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get the field name
        var quantity = parseInt($('#quantity').val());
        
        // If is not undefined
      
            // Increment
    if(quantity>0){
    $('#quantity').val(quantity - 1);
}
});
    
});
</script>
```