# text box (not input) next to button in bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have this ("CIR", "+" and "-" are buttons):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N01Hk.png)

And I want this ("0" could be any number-string, so when I press "+" or "-" it will increment or decrement respectively (I know how to do it with JS)):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R67Bw.png)

The code I have at this moment is:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="initCir">CIR</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" @click="incCir">+</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-light mr-2" @click="decCir">-</button>
</div>
```

I've been searching but couldn't find anything in documentation of Bootstrap or others question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after an hour of trying a lot of things with CSS, I came with a solution that work (at least for my purposes):

```
<div id="btn-counter-cir" class="btn btn-light" style="pointer-events: none">Something</div>
```

[image: Check this Image]

Then with `document.getElementById("btn-counter-cir").innerHTML = 0;` I can do what I wanted for increment and decrement with the respectively buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this person had the same issue.. don't want to steal the answer, but the person did a good job explaining it.

[Increment and decrement a number with Bootstrap design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48800740/increment-and-decrement-a-number-with-bootstrap-design)

```
<input type="text" name="quant[1]" class="form-control input-number" value="1" min="1" max="10">

<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="initCir">CIR</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" @click="incCir" data-field="quant[1]" data-type="plus">+</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-light mr-2" @click="decCir" data-field="quant[1]" data-type="minus">-</button>
</div>
```